# Why my program does not run second for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I was trying to make baseball game that counts strike and ball.
For example, if random_number is '835' and user_input_number is '853', strike_count should be 1, ball_count should be 2.
And this function is only for counting strike and ball.
But the program does not run the second for loop for counting ball.
So I can't count ball.

```
def get_strikes_or_ball(user_input_number, random_number):

    random_number_list = list(random_number)
    print("random_number_list: ", random_number_list)
    user_input_number_list = list(user_input_number)
    print("user_input_number_list: ", user_input_number_list)

    strike_count = 0

    for i in range(0, 3):
        print("first for")
        if random_number_list[i] == user_input_number_list[i]:
            strike_count += 1

    print("start")

    ball_count = 0

    for i in range(2, -1):
        print("second for")
        for k in range(1, 3):
            if random_number_list[i] == user_input_number_list[i-k]:
                ball_count += 1

    print("st, ball: ", strike_count, ball_count)
    result = [strike_count, ball_count]

    # ==================================
    return result
```

Comment: Try printing `[x for x in range(2, -1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range `range(2, -1)` is empty. If you want to get the reversed range `[-1, 2)` you can use `reversed(range(-1, 2))`.

Comment: You can also use `for i in range(2, -1, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

Python's range function accepts 3 parameters, two of which are optional.  Start, stop, and step.  Start and step are optional.  The default for start is 0, and the default for step is 1.  If you want to step in the negative direction, you need to pass -1 for step.  Replacing `range(2, -1)` with `range(2, -1, -1)` should solve your problem, and this will be more efficient than using the reversed() function.

Answer (score 0):

In for loop parameter, there are three parameters in python  for(start, stop(excluded number), step) there must be compulsory to define stop in loop if you don't specify it will get your third parameter as the second parameter and if you have to decrement the value of loop then you must give step as -1 it decrements as value -1 each time.

```
def get_strikes_or_ball(user_input_number, random_number):

random_number_list = list(random_number)
print("random_number_list: ", random_number_list)
user_input_number_list = list(user_input_number)
print("user_input_number_list: ", user_input_number_list)

strike_count = 0

for i in range(0, 3):
    print("first for")
    if random_number_list[i] == user_input_number_list[i]:
        strike_count += 1

print("start")

ball_count = 0

for i in range(2, -1,-1):
    print("second for")
    for k in range(1, 3):
        if random_number_list[i] == user_input_number_list[i-k]:
            ball_count += 1

print("st, ball: ", strike_count, ball_count)
result = [strike_count, ball_count]

# ==================================
return result
```